# Add data in Input(box) to sql db through javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

Here is my code which I am using to write the data in input(box) "latitude" and "longitude" to database using c# code inside javascript.

All I want is that the data gets inserted whenever the button is pressed. This code only inserts data once at the time of initialization. No effect occurs onButtonClick.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Markers.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #google_map {width: 550px; height: 450px;margin-top:50px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(33.650077, 73.034054); //Google map Coordinates
    var map
    var marker
    var marker1


    function initialize() //function initializes Google map
    {
        var googleMapOptions =
        {
            center: mapCenter, // map center
            zoom: 15, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value
            panControl: true, //enable pan Control
            zoomControl: true, //enable zoom control
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL //zoom control size
            },
            scaleControl: true, // enable scale control
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mapCenter,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: "This a new marker!",
            icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
        });
        marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mapCenter,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            title: "This a new marker!",
            icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
            document.getElementById('latitude').value = evt.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById('longitude').value = evt.latLng.lng();

        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', function (evt) {
            document.getElementById('latitude1').value = evt.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById('longitude1').value = evt.latLng.lng();
        });

    }
    function addMyMarker() { //function that will add markers on button click
        <%    Markers.DataClasses1DataContext db = new Markers.DataClasses1DataContext();%>
        <%    Markers.LocationDataPacket l = new Markers.LocationDataPacket(); %>               
        <%     l.cellPhoneGPSData = 1; %>
        <%      DateTime dt = DateTime.Now ;          %>  
        <%     l.Lat = Convert.ToDouble(latitude.Value.ToString());%>
        <%    l.time = dt; %>
        <%     l.Long = Convert.ToDouble(longitude.Value.ToString()); %>
        <%      db.LocationDataPackets.InsertOnSubmit(l); %>
        <% save(db);     %>
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="initialize()">
<div id="google_map" ></div><button id="drop" onClick="addMyMarker()">Drop Markers</button>
  <input id="latitude" runat="server" value="3.33" />
  <input id="longitude" type="text" runat="server" value="3.33" />
  <input id="latitude1" type="text" value="3.33"/>
  <input id="longitude1" type="text" value="3.33"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no experience of coding in javascript.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: there is no way to directly execut server side code from javascript, you will have to call some sort of web service to perform the server side functions.

Comment: @BenRobinson have you tried it? Can I have a link of an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript runs client side and cannot have c# "embedded" into it, to do this i would move the c# code to its own page and use AJAX to send/receive data to the server and execute the c# code accordingly

Comment: Can you please share any example's link?

And how about writing to file and reading from there? Does javascript allows that? I was trying to create file but it wasn't creating any

Comment: JavaScript creates runs EXCLUSIVELY on the client, in your example, the C# runs EXCLUSIVELY on the server. you cannot interact with files between the two. You cannot pass variables between the two like this. The code you have produced will run the JavaScript at the client upon button click, and run the c# code on the server when the page loads. You must apply methods of communicating between the client and the server.